# Multi Hierarchy ID Generation

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a PHP project in "`multi hierarchy ID generation`" Like Let Me explain how it works.

If suppose 10 products packed in one box, In the same way there are 10 Box's are with 10 Products each and then all these 10 box's should packed in one container

Note: 1 Container has 10 box's and each box has 10 products.

So, I have Unique Id's for every product if i get that id i can get product Details, Now i need to generate an id for 10 box's and along with 1 container, If i get the id of each box i will get product information of all the 10 products and if i get id of container i should get information of all the 10 Box's along with that i should get product information of each box.
*Note:
If I scan container Id I should get all the 10 box's Info and product details of each box.
If I scan each box id in container I should get all 10 products Information*
Please give me a logic how to do this `multi hierarchy method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Hierarchy Level can generate through For loop

```
<?php  
$primary = 2; // These values may change
$secondary = 1; // These values may change
$tertiary = 2;

if($primary == 0 && $secondary > 0){
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $secondary; $j++) {

        echo("Secondary: " . $j."<br/>");

        for ($k = 1; $k <= $tertiary; $k++) {
             echo($j."->". $k."<br/>");
        }
    }
}elseif($primary > 0){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $primary; $i++) {


        echo('Primary: ' . $i."<br/>");

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $secondary; $j++) {

            echo('Primary: ' . $i . "- Secondary: " . $j."<br/>");

            for ($k = 1; $k <= $tertiary; $k++) {
                echo('Primary: ' . $i . "- Secondary: " . $j . "- Tertiary: " . $k."<br/>");
            }
        }
    }
}elseif($primary == 0 && $secondary == 0){
    for ($k = 1; $k <= $tertiary; $k++) {
        echo("Tertiary: " . $k."<br/>");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No This the Perfect Answer..am using the same logic for generating codes

Comment: Right, then don't forget to accept it once you can so the question doesn't look unanswered

Answer (score 0):

If these are "fixed" numbers, an easy approach may be to use some maths:

- `product-id` ranges from 0-9 (so, upto 10 products)
- `box-id` ranges from 0-9 (so, upto 10 boxes)
- `container-id` just grows, as the number of containers is unknown.

so, start your container with id `1` and append the box-id, followed by the product-id:

`2539` will tell you:

- Container 25
- Box 3
- Product 9

To query a whole box, query for `id >= 2530 and id <= 2539`. To query a whole container, query for `id >= 2500 and id <=2599`.